# Why does same expression in different forms give different integration results?

Tags: integration

Let's take this expression $\frac{x^3} {x^2 +1}$ as an example.

When I take the indefinite integral $\int \frac{x^3} {x^2 +1} dx$, I get the following result: $$\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 1 - ln|x^2 + 1| + C$$

However, if I write the original expression in a different form, as $x - \frac{x}{x^2 +1}$, and take the integral now $\int ( x- \frac{x} {x^2 +1} )dx$, I will get a similar result: $$\frac{1}{2}(x^2 - ln|x^2 + 1| + C$$

Where did the $+1$ from the first result come from? Which one is correct?

Comment: The primitive (indefinite integral) of a function is determined *only* up to the sum of a constant, so if you get something plus or minus *any* number then it is the same...assuming the derivative equals the integrand, of course.

Comment: @user 321070 : Your $C$ has the meaning of "any constant". So, you can write $C$, or $C+1$, or $C+205$, or $C-2.325$ , or ... All these answers are equivalent until the integral is an undefined integral.

Comment: @JJacquelin That hit me hard! Thank you! It was confusing since the answer sheet has it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that the $+1$ is just another constant; thanks for other users pointing it out!